# For Hadoop: which data storage?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, store

Currently I am working on a solution for my internship to handle up to 100.000.000 records a day with about 10 columns. I have to save each record, and after 15 days we have about 1.500.000.000 records.

**The situation:**
So, every day I receive about 100.000.000 (maybe a few millions more) records, with these records I have to do some calculations/analyzing. To do this, I am thinking about to use Hadoop for MapReduce and distributed computing. With the MapReduce pattern I can make sets of 100.000 records each, and distribute them over the cluster to do some distributed analyzing/calculations

I don't know if this is a good solution, but if you have something else I have to think about, please tell me.

Beside this, I also have to store all these records and use them every month to improve the algorithm for the calculations I do every day. What store is best for this situation? I am thinking about HBase or CouchDB because I think they fit my requirements well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually , Hadoop is not a database.Hadoop is a framework that enables the distributed processing of large data sets across clusters of commodity servers.
It is designed to scale up from a single server to thousands of machines, with a very high degree of fault tolerance. Hadoop is best known for MapReduce and its distributed file system (HDFS)

Hbase is a distributed, column-oriented database. Hbase uses HDFS for its underlying storage, and supports both batch-style computations using MapReduce and point queries.

Hive is a distributed data warehouse. Hive manages data stored in HDFS and provides a query language based on SQL (and which is translated by the runtime engine to MapReduce jobs) for queering the data.

**What you can do is:
using  [Hbase](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_read_hbase_shell_commands_from_a_command_file) for storage

using hive for analytics

you can also [integrate](http://hadooptutorial.info/hbase-integration-with-hive/#Setup_for_HBase_Integration_with_Hive) both and use hive queries (based on sql) to store in hbase.

Comment: Hi Yosr, you are right about Hadoop, it's not a database. I have fixed that in my question now. Thanks for answer. I will do some more investigation. If I have a decision which solution I will use, I will definitely tell you. Thanks :)

Comment: you are welcome and if you want to know more about Hadoop you should begin by reading 'Hadoop the definitive guide 3rd edition '